# How to add custom span into Trace, in go

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-platform, trace, google-cloud-stackdriver

My app runs on App Engine **Standard** and the Go runtime.
I have this trace for my recent request:

[image: Trace of my request in Stackdriver Trace]

There is a big gap between the "urlfetch" span and the "datastore_v3" span, because my app processes some CPU-bound computation for ~1000ms.

I would love to programmatically add my computation as **a custom span** into the Trace view, and get something like this:

[image]

Is there a way to do this in my app written in go? ([source here](https://github.com/Deleplace/samples/tree/master/custom-trace-span/appengine-standard-go))

Comment: @Flimzy I will have to edit again the title and the question, as it specifically applies to GAE **standard** and the go runtime. Tags only partly address this. The same question is relevant to the Java, Python, Go, Php and NodeJS runtimes but calls for different answers in each case, thus I intend to create 5 similar questions.

Comment: That's all fine, but there's still no reason to put "in go" in the title--the tags cover this. Read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/165502) for further explanation.

Comment: Thanks for the META link, it is indeed explicit. In this case we will end up with 5 questions having the same title which I hope won't cause too much confusion.

Answer (score 0):

It appears it *might* be possible. From [Setting Up Stackdriver Trace for Go](https://cloud.google.com/trace/docs/setup/go):

> **Alpha**
>
> This is an alpha release of the [OpenCensus](https://github.com/census-instrumentation/opencensus-go) package for Go. These
>   libraries might be changed in backward-incompatible ways and are not
>   recommended for production use. They are not subject to any SLA or
>   deprecation policy.
>
> Stackdriver Trace can be used by Go applications using the
>   [OpenCensus](https://github.com/census-instrumentation/opencensus-go) package for Go.
>
> Stackdriver Trace's Go support is provided by [OpenCensus](https://opencensus.io/), a set
>   of tracing and application metrics instrumentation libraries that work
>   with multiple backends. The latest details about OpenCensus for Go,
>   along with additional documentation and examples, can be found on its
>   [GitHub page](https://github.com/census-instrumentation/opencensus-go).

Support is enabled by default in the flexible environment, however the docs make no mention about the standard environment (if that's your case I'd say just give it a try). From [App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/trace/docs/setup/go#app_engine):

> On Google App Engine flexible environment, the Stackdriver Trace API
>   access scope is enabled by default, and the [OpenCensus](https://github.com/census-instrumentation/opencensus-go) client
>   library can be used without needing to provide credentials or a
>   project ID.

An application [code sample](https://cloud.google.com/trace/docs/setup/go#wzxhzdk13wzxhzdk14sample_product_name_application_for_go) is provided on the same page.

Comment: Indeed GAE standard is not explicitly supported according to this doc. I tried this package but (as of June 2018) the go.opencensus.io/exporter/stackdriver complains with "panic: not an App Engine context", which I couldn't work around.

Answer (score 0):

I could make it work with [the new AppEngine runtime for Go 1.11](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go111/go-differences) (currently in beta) and [OpenCensus](https://github.com/census-instrumentation/opencensus-go) with the [Stackdriver exporter](https://godoc.org/contrib.go.opencensus.io/exporter/stackdriver).

[image]

In order to attach my custom span to the main Trace of the request, I use this utility func:

```
// Start a new span "With Remote Parent"
func startSpanfWRT(r *http.Request, msg string, args ...interface{}) (c2 context.Context, endSpan func()) {
    caption := fmt.Sprintf(msg, args...)
    c := r.Context()

    spanContext, ok := (&propagation.HTTPFormat{}).SpanContextFromRequest(r)
    if !ok {
        return c, func() {}
    }
    var span *trace.Span
    c2, span = trace.StartSpanWithRemoteParent(c, caption, spanContext)
    endSpan = func() {
        span.End()
    }
    return c2, endSpan
}
```

Note that it requires the `*http.Request` as argument (a `context.Context` wouldn't be enough here).

Here is [the sample app source code](https://github.com/Deleplace/samples/tree/master/custom-trace-span/appengine-standard-go/go111).

As a span needs to be *started* and then later *stopped*, the start func returns an "end" callback, and a new Context as well.

It is fine to call `startSpanfWRT` multiple times, and they may overlap. It requires to pass the `*http.Request` around, which is not super-convenient (usually we only pass Contexts around).

However, after a call to `startSpanfWRT`, you may add children spans conveniently, just paying attention to the respective Contexts:

```
c2, childSpan := trace.StartSpan(c, caption)
```

[image: Span having child span]

[image: Span with child span]